# How to display gif image randomly using Swift 3 (Xcode 8.1)?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift3

I am new to Swift 3, currently doing a simple app, to display random gif images while user touching the screen. I have 2 gif images, when user touches the screen, it will display either one. How do I make it to display randomly?

Answer (score 2):

For Example, I use this Library for view gif image: https://github.com/kirualex/SwiftyGif

```
 var imagesName:[String] = ["image1.gif","image2.gif"]
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard touches.count == 1 else {
            return
        }
       let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(1))

        if let touch = touches.first {
            self.gifImageView.image = UIImage(gifName: self.imagesName[index])
        }
    }
```